ARIMA Model Forecasting - 95% Prediction Intervals
I'm currently learning about time series forecasting and ARIMA models. For this question, I'll just be using the AR(1) model example $X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$ and say we are forecasting $X_{t+1}$
One resource I've come across is [Forecasting: Principles and Practice][1] (Hyndman and Athanasopoulos), which states that:

The first prediction interval is easy to calculate. If $\hat{\sigma}$ is the standard deviation of the residuals, then a 95% prediction interval is given by  $\hat{y}_{T+1|T} \pm 1.96 \hat{\sigma^2}$


This seems to imply that when computing the predictional interval (or forecast interval), we are purely considering the variance / uncertainty in the future error term that will "disrupt" our $X_{t+1}$ forecast

But when reading this answer on CrossValidated: ARIMA forecast confidence intervals, it seems to state that $Var(X_{T+1}) = Var(\phi) + Var(\varepsilon_{T+1})$. Note, the question is titled confidence interval which I understand relates to parameter estimation, not forecasting, but the OP seems to be asking about the forecast / prediction interval

This second source seems to state that the prediction interval incorporates the variance of the AR parameter as well as that of the future error term

My question is how can I reconcile the discrepancy here, and what is the correct way to compute a forecast interval for $X_{t+1}$ forecast?

The textbook Forecasting: Principles and Practice mentions explicitly that they ignore the uncertainty in the parameter estimates when calculating the forecast intervals. Here is the last paragraph of section 8.8 from the 2nd edition:

As with most prediction interval calculations, ARIMA-based intervals tend to be too narrow. This occurs because only the variation in the errors has been accounted for. There is also variation in the parameter estimates, and in the model order, that has not been included in the calculation. In addition, the calculation assumes that the historical patterns that have been modelled will continue into the forecast period.

The reason for not accounting for the uncertainty mentioned above is that it tends to be much smaller than the uncertainty due to the randomness of the error, so that ignoring the former does not hurt much.
